# Object inside an array keep the old obj reference after changing obj value

Tags: javascript

could someone please explain me this:

```
let obj = {name: 'puki'}
const arr = [obj]
arr[0] === obj // true (same ref address)
obj = null
console.log(arr) // [{name: 'puki'}]
```

how come the array is keeping the old obj ref?

Comment: hi, sorry if it wasnt clear. its just to explain the mem[0] === obj line

Comment: I think you mean `arr[0] === obj` to keep the naming consistent (or `const mem = [obj];`

Comment: true, forgot to change it as i was copying from my console :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing an object reference and the object itself.

In your code `obj` is a reference (an address) to the actual object `{name: 'puki'}`

The array also stores the reference (the address) to the actual object.

When you overwrite the reference `obj` with `null` you're not actually modifying the actual object `{name: 'puki'}` or the target of the address, you're just overwriting the reference (pointer) with the null pointer / value. There is no dereferencing in Javascript like it exists in C / C++

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you are not deleting the object, but rather the pointer to it. Object variables are actually pointers to the object itself. So that's why you can have many pointers to same object. Each will affect it. But removing a pointer doesn't remove the object **unless** it's the final pointer to it.